# publishing facebook group photo gallery in my webpage

Tags: facebook, gallery, facebook-apps, facebook-group

I am trying to publish a photo gallery from a facebook group onto my webpage, i found some nice code at http://www.codeofaninja.com/2011/06/display-facebook-photos-to-your-website.html, but dont know how to create an app that connects to that fb group and how to select pictures to display on webpage and stuff. I already created the app, now just need a way to connect it to the group, so the code that gets the app id and app secret can find and display pictures...

Answer (score 1):

Applications can't be "connected" to the group. What you need is to authenticate the user (requesting `user_groups` permission to access groups information) and than retrieve `feed` to get images associated with `posts`.

Once you have id of the group you may do call like this to retrieve posts:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/feed?fields=picture
```

Than iterate over posts to get images.

Beware that `picture` field contain unusable URL and the real URL should be extracted from it (it's present in `url` argument in URL encoded form).

Answer (score 0):

The URL gives you ALL (well last 100M) photo and video posts, since the group creation date, with photo/video "object_id" and FB locations (if added)

**/me/GROUP_ID/feed?fields=object_id,place&limit=100000000&since=DATE_TIME_STAMP_WHEN_GROUP_WAS_CREATED&type=photo,video**

The you need to walk through all **object_id's** and pull URL's to desired image's size.

**/me/OBJECT_ID?fields=images**

I still don't understand how to find ALL object_id's connected to a particular post. I mean if more than one photo was attached...